# How to encrypt with iOS CryptoKit and decrypt with C# in NetCore

Tags: c#, swift, encryption, encryption-symmetric, apple-cryptokit

I would like to encrypt data in iOS app with a SymetricKey and the CryptoKit and decrypt on server side with C# in Net Core.

iOS code:

```
class Security {
    
    static let keyStr = "d5a423f64b607ea7c65b311d855dc48f"  //32
    static let iv="31348c0987c7"    //12
    
    class func encode(_ text:String)->String {
        let key=SymmetricKey(data: Security.keyStr.data(using: .utf8)!)
        let nonce=try! AES.GCM.Nonce(data: iv.data(using: .utf8)!)
        let encrypted=try! AES.GCM.seal(text.data(using: .utf8)!, using: key, nonce: nonce)
        

        return encrypted.combined!.base64EncodedString()
    }
    
}
```

I pass the result of the encryption to my backend and I would like to decrypt

C# Code:

```
public string decrypt(string encryptedText)
        {
            string keyStr = "d5a423f64b607ea7c65b311d855dc48f";
            string iv = "31348c0987c7";

            string plaintext = "";

        Debug.WriteLine(encryptedText);

        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(AesGcm.IsSupported);

            var key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyStr);
            var iV = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iv);
            aesAlg.Key = key;
            aesAlg.IV = iV;

            // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(request.pswd)))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {

                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                        // and place them in a string.
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(plaintext);

    }
```

So for example word: Test gets encrypted as: MzEzNDhjMDk4N2M3CI68IDEJeBR4OFtWO3GPO3TIgos=

When I get to line:

```
aesAlg.IV = iV;
```

I get an error "Specified initialization vector (IV) does not match the block size for this algorithm."
It seems as if C# needs byte[16], but in iOS I seem to be stuck with 12.

I got stuck at this point. Any idea greately appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posted Swift code applies AES in GCM mode, s. [`AES.GCM`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/aes/gcm). The posted C# code also uses AES, however not the GCM mode, but the default CBC mode (s. [`Aes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-7.0), [`Mode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.mode?view=net-7.0#system-security-cryptography-symmetricalgorithm-mode)).
The CBC mode applies a 16 bytes IV, while the GCM mode uses a 12 bytes nonce. That is what the error message is pointing to.
For successful decryption, AES in GCM mode must also be used on the C# side. In .NET AES in GCM mode is supported with the [`AesGcm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesgcm?view=net-7.0) class (as of .NET Core 3.0).

Note also that the data given by the Swift code is the Base64 encoding of the concatenation of 12 bytes nonce, ciphertext and 16 bytes tag (in that order), which must be separated in the C# code, where the portions are processed individually.

A possible C# implementation that decrypts the ciphertext generated by the posted Swift code is:

```
byte[] nonceCiphertextTag = Convert.FromBase64String("MzEzNDhjMDk4N2M3CI68IDEJeBR4OFtWO3GPO3TIgos=");
byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("d5a423f64b607ea7c65b311d855dc48f");

Span<byte> nonceCiphertextTagSpan = nonceCiphertextTag.AsSpan();
Span<byte> nonce = nonceCiphertextTagSpan[..12];
Span<byte> ciphertext = nonceCiphertextTagSpan[12..^16];
Span<byte> tag = nonceCiphertextTagSpan[^16..];
byte[] plaintext = new byte[ciphertext.Length];

using AesGcm aesGcm = new AesGcm(key);
aesGcm.Decrypt(nonce, ciphertext, tag, plaintext); // throws an 'CryptographicException: The computed authentication tag did not match the input authentication tag' if authentication fails

Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plaintext)); // Test
```

---

**Edit**: An alternative to the native .NET class `AesGcm` is C#/BouncyCastle. Maybe this is supported in your environment:

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Modes;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
...
byte[] nonceCiphertextTag = Convert.FromBase64String("MzEzNDhjMDk4N2M3CI68IDEJeBR4OFtWO3GPO3TIgos=");
byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("d5a423f64b607ea7c65b311d855dc48f");

Span<byte> nonceCiphertextTagSpan = nonceCiphertextTag.AsSpan();
byte[] nonce = nonceCiphertextTagSpan[..12].ToArray();
byte[] ciphertextTag = nonceCiphertextTagSpan[12..].ToArray();

GcmBlockCipher gcmBlockCipher = new GcmBlockCipher(new AesEngine());
AeadParameters aeadParameters = new AeadParameters(new KeyParameter(key), 128, nonce);
gcmBlockCipher.Init(false, aeadParameters);
byte[] plaintext = new byte[gcmBlockCipher.GetOutputSize(ciphertextTag.Length)];
int length = gcmBlockCipher.ProcessBytes(ciphertextTag, 0, ciphertextTag.Length, plaintext, 0);
gcmBlockCipher.DoFinal(plaintext, length); // throws an 'InvalidCipherTextException: mac check in GCM failed' if authentication fails

Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plaintext)); // Test
```

Note that unlike the native `AesGcm` class, C#/BouncyCastle requires the concatenation of ciphertext and tag, so only the nonce needs to be separated.

Comment: Thank you Topaco, as I run Net Core side via the Visual Studio for Mac, I am getting another error that the "Algorithm 'AesGcm' is not supported on this platform." Any recommendation or should I move to Visual Studio for Windows? I have Windows installed on my Mac via Paralles. So that could be a way.

Comment: @matyasl - If *Visual Studio for Mac* really doesn't provide its own imlpementation for AES/GCM (I can neither confirm nor deny this, as I don't know *Visual Studio for Mac*), a third-party library might be an alternative, e.g. C#/BouncyCastle, see the Edit-section in my answer. If this is also not compatible in your environment,  you may really have no choice but to switch to *Visual Studio for Windows*.

Comment: Hello Topaco, thank you again. For the moment I opted for Visual Studio for Windows in Parallels. It took me some time to configure it so that I can reach it from an iOS Simulator on the Mac. But I have just managed to test your solution and it works. Many thanks!!!